# Email for Low Stock Products

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.0.1, stock, cataloginventory

How can I **setup the Email Notification for the Low Stock Products and Expired Products**?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Magento does not support **email notifications** for out of stock products.

However, there is an RSS feed available out of the box in the backend to be notified about low stock products:

[image]

To get notified via email, you can either develop your own custom module (which could be long and complex) or you can use a 3rd party service that automatically sends an email based on a RSS feed such as https://blogtrottr.com/ for example

Answer (score 2):

You can create a module that has an observer and depending on where you want to check the inventory, observer those events, like product_save_after and checkout_submit_all_after events.

An observer would look like something below:

In config.xml:

```
      <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <lowstock>
                    <class>lowstock/observer</class>
                    <method>sendLowStockEmailCheckout</method>
                </lowstock>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
     <events>
```

In Observer.php

```
<?php

class Vendor_Lowstockalert_Model_Observer
{

    public function sendLowStockEmailCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $items = array();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId  = $item->getProductId();

            if (!$productId) {
                continue;
            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

            if ($product) {
                $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
                $items[$productId] = array(
                    'item' => $stockItem,
                    'qty'  => $stockItem->getQty()
                );
            }

            if (count($items) > 0) {
                if ($items[$productId]['qty'] <= $items[$productId]['item']->getMinQty()) {
                    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $templateId = 'low_stock';

                    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateId);
                    $vars = array('product_name' => $items[$productId]['item']->getProductName(), 'qty' => $items[$productId]['qty']);

                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId));

                    $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));

                    try {
                        $emailTemplate->send(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId), Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId), $vars);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        Mage::log("Unable to complete. Error: " . $e->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```